# Dribbble API returning mismatching counts for things like shot comments

Tags: ajax

I have been working with the Dribbble API recently and have come across a strange bug whereby the purported comments_count doesn't match the amount of returned comments.

I have created a codepen for you guys that demonstrates the issue.

Is this an issue with the API or am I missing something here?

http://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/bdxwoV?editors=011

Here's the code from said example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots/?per_page=20',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer 75913cbbec4e93dae61f6d4bfa9ba3ae35fe62b4cf2c3aa074f171e4e7f62996');
    },
    success: function(data){
        $(data).each(function(){
            var comments_count = this.comments_count;

            $.ajax({
                url: this.comments_url,
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer 75913cbbec4e93dae61f6d4bfa9ba3ae35fe62b4cf2c3aa074f171e4e7f62996');
                },
                success: function(data){
                    var mismatch = comments_count !== data.length ? true : false;
                    if(mismatch){
                        $('.out').append('<p class="mismatch">There should be ' + comments_count + ' comments, but there are actually ' + data.length + '</p>');
                    } else {
                        $('.out').append('<p>There should be ' + comments_count + ' comments, but there are actually ' + data.length + '</p>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```